# Interpreting the graph of $g(x) = \int_0^x f(t)dt$

Tags: calculus

***Disclaimer: I am not a lazy student trying to get free internet homework help. I am an adult who is learning Calculus from a textbook.  I am deeply grateful to the members of this community for their time.***

I made up a graph and wanted to make up questions about it.
I just wanted to clarify 2 answers I got.

Note that $g(x) = \int_0^x f(t)dt$

So, $g'(x) = f(x) $

and $g''(x) = f'(x)$

1) x=3 is indeed a relative max, correct?  Since it's one of the bounds, the derivative doesn't change sign at 3, but g(x) is increasing all the way to x=3.

2) Inflection point is where $g''(x) = f'(x)$ changes sign.  Well, this happens where $f(x)$ changes slope (reverses direction).  This happens at $x=-2.$  But, what is the deal with the flat part of the graph at [0,3]?  It technically reverses direction but only after a flat part from [1,2].  Is my below conclusion correct?  Is there a better way to explain this?

[image]

Comment: Can you upload the picture to anything *but* tinypic? They made it tiny and I can't see anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes. $g(x)$ has a *relative* max at $x=3$ for that interval. This is because the area from $x=0$ to $x=3$ is greater than the area from $x=0$ to $x=-3$ *minus* the rest of the area there (recall: $\int_0^{-3}=-\int_{-3}^0=$ positive for negative area). I wouldn't really look at derivatives to figure that one out because, if $f(3)$ was at a point higher than 0, the value of $g(3)$ would be even higher. Slopes are more of to determine extrema, which are not necessarily maximum/minimum values of an interval.

2) As far as I know (and correct me if I'm wrong), you're right - there is no inflection point because there isn't a point where the second derivatives of the points to the left and right sides have different signs. And $x=-2$ is indeed an inflection point even though $f'(-2)$ is undefined.

Comment: Isn't it easier to just consider that g(x) is increasing on the interval [0,3] so x=3 must be a relative max?

Comment: @JackOfAll In this case you can, but in other cases it won't be so obvious.

Comment: Wait, I'm not sure I follow what you were saying about comparing areas.

Comment: @JackOfAll $g(x)$ is the area under $f(x)$ from $x=0$. If you look to the right of the y-axis, you will see that the area is positive and hence $g(x)$ is getting bigger and bigger. To the left, however, you will take any area and multiply it by $-1$ (because the integral is from $0$). So the little section below will be positive (hence $g(x)$ will grow, but the area is much lower), and then the rest will be negative, so you don't care about that. the area under $f(x)$ to $-3$ is smaller than that to $3$, so $g(-3)<g(3)$.

Comment: Shahar, you are very good at explaining things.  To recap:  G is increasing on (0,3) since enclosed area is getting bigger.  Next, you compared g(3) to g(-3) since it's another critical point where $g'(x)=f(x)=0$.  On the negative side, the integral limits are reversed and the area is "negative".  Double negative  = (+).  So g(x) where x is within (-3,0) is also positive.  As you get closer to -3, the total area is increasing.  So g(x) is decreasing on (-3,0)?  But, g(-3) has less enclosed area than g(3).  So both are positive, but $g(-3)<g(3)$.  Correct?  Thanks!!

Comment: Yep! Exactly what I was trying to say.